# Find out which words in a large list occur in a small string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a static 'large' list of words, about 300-500 words, called 'list1'

given a relatively short string `str` of about 40 words, what is the fastest method in ruby to get:

1. the number of times a word in `list1` occurs in `str` (counting multiple occurrences)
2. a list of which words in `list1` occur one or more times in the string str
3. the number of words in (2)

'Occuring' in `str` means either as a whole word in `str`, or as a partial within a word in `str`. So if `'fred'` is in `list1` and `str` contained `'fred'` and `'freddie'` that would be two matches.

Everything is lowercase, so any matching does not have to care about case.

For example:

```
list1 ="fred sam sandy jack sue bill"
str = "and so sammy went with jack to see fred and freddie"
```

so `str` contains `sam`, `jack`, `fred` (twice)

for part (1) the expression would return 4 (sam+jack+fred+fred)
for part (2) the expression would return "sam jack fred"
and part (3) is 3

The 'ruby way' to do this eludes me after 4 hours... with iteration it's easy enough (but slow). Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my shot at it:

```
def match_freq(exprs, strings)
  rs, ss, f = exprs.split.map{|x|Regexp.new(x)}, strings.split, {}
  rs.each{|r| ss.each{|s| f[r] = f[r] ? f[r]+1 : 1 if s=~r}}
  [f.values.inject(0){|a,x|a+x}, f, f.size]
end

list1 = "fred sam sandy jack sue bill"
str = "and so sammy went with jack to see fred and freddie"
x = match_freq(list1, str)
x # => [4, {/sam/=>1, /fred/=>2, /jack/=>1}, 3]
```

The output of "match_freq" is an array of your output items (a,b,c).  The algorithm itself is `O(n*m)` where `n` is the number of items in list1 and `m` is the size of the input string, I don't think you can do better than that (in terms of big-oh).  But there are smaller optimizations that might pay off like keeping a separate counter for the total number of matches instead of computing it afterwards.  This was just my quick hack at it.

You can extract just the matching words from the output as follows:

```
matches = x[1].keys.map{|x|x.source}.join(" ") # => "sam fred jack"
```

Note that the order won't be preserved necessarily, if that's important you'll have to keep a separate list of the order they were found.

Comment: i'll be darned. wow. you rock. took me a while to wade through it in irb one step at a time, but that's very cool. i also didn't know how to return multiple values from a function so that was a useful tidbit also!

Comment: what is the easiest way to extract "sam fred jack" from {/sam/=>1, /fred/=>2, /jack/=>1}?

Comment: @jpwynn: I updated the answer to show how to extract those values.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative implementation, for your edification:

```
def match_freq( words, str )
  words  = words.split(/\s+/)
  counts = Hash[ words.map{ |w| [w,str.scan(w).length] } ]
  counts.delete_if{ |word,ct| ct==0 }
  occurring_words = counts.keys
  [
    counts.values.inject(0){ |sum,ct| sum+ct }, # Sum of counts
    occurring_words,
    occurring_words.length
  ]
end

list1 = "fred sam sandy jack sue bill"
str   = "and so sammy went with jack to see fred and freddie"
x     = match_freq(list1, str)
p x   #=> [4, ["fred", "sam", "jack"], 3]
```

Note that if I needed this data I would probably just return the 'counts' hash from the method and then do whatever analysis I wanted on it. If I was going to return multiple 'values' from an analysis method, I might return a Hash of named values. Although, returning an array allows you to *unsplat* the results:

```
hits, words, word_count = match_freq(list1, str)
p hits, words, word_count  
#=> 4
#=> ["fred", "sam", "jack"]
#=> 3
```

Comment: Note that this algorithm actually is O(n) (construction of hash map) / O(m) (access to words happens in constant time). So if you process many input strings str or the number of words in list1 is really big, this algorithm should be faster.

Comment: This one is `O(n*m)` also, as must be any solution to this problem. Note that `words.map` is O(n) and it nests [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001181) which is O(m) (where m is string length), hence O(n*m). Intuitively, if you're finding all `n` patterns in a string of length `m` then the solution must be O(m*n).

Answer (score 0):

For **faster regular expressions**, use https://github.com/mudge/re2. It is a ruby wrapper for **Google re2** https://code.google.com/p/re2/