# reverse include for array?

Tags: ruby

I want to check whether **any item from the array is part of a string**. Something like `.include?`

I wrote a function for that but I am sure there would be a **simpler way**.

Could someone suggest how I use **less code to achieve the same**?

```
$goes_into_cron_comments=["Edumate_upgrade","login"].map!{|item| item.downcase} 
params={}
params['run']="login_ldap"

def contains(array,string)
        array.each{|item| 
            if string.include?(string)
                return true
            end
        }
        return false
end
#if ($goes_into_cron_comments.include?(params['run'].downcase)) #original condition
if (contains($goes_into_cron_comments,params['run'].downcase))
    puts "contains"
else 
    puts "doesn't contain"
end
```

Comment: Similar question: [Find out which words in a large list occur in a small string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4859733/405017).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are things you can do that would be nicer. You could use [`Enumerable#any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) rather than iterating by hand:

```
array.any? { |item| string.include?(item) }
```

Or you could use [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-union):

```
string =~ Regexp.union(array)
# or if you want a true boolean
!!(string =~ Regexp.union(array))
!(string =~ Regexp.union(array)).nil?
```

Comment: +1 Came here for the more-efficient regex answer, leaving extra satisfied due to the usage of `union`.

Comment: Why regex that more-efficient?

Comment: @Radek: The regex engine can look at all the elements of `array` at once so it *may* be faster for larger arrays.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
str = 'hey, this is a string'
arr = %w{one hey may}

arr.any? { |el| str.include? el }
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just do something like this:

```
def contains?(array,string)
    array.index{|item| string.include?(item)}
end
```

Index will return a truthy/falsy value, so this is probably the 'cleanest' way to do it.  I would also include the ? at the end of your function definition just to make it clearer how it should be used and what result to expect.

Comment: I changed my code to `if ($goes_into_cron_comments.index{|item| params['run'].downcase.include?(item)})` and I am always getting true regardless if the array contains the `correct` string. In your code should be ... `.include?(item)` ...

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't change that bit from your example :)