# [Ruby]How to search multiple keywords in a single string line

Tags: ruby, search, keyword

I am new to ruby. I want to know how to find if multiple keywords exist or not in a single line. For example, a line "Hello, how are you?", if "Hello" or "how" exits, return true.
I try to use reg exp like /Hello|how/, but performance is not good when there are lots of lines to process. 
Maybe Regexp suits this use case, but I cannot find specific example in google.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859733/find-out-which-words-in-a-large-list-occur-in-a-small-string

Answer (score 2):

```
keywords = {
  "Hello" => true,
  "how" => true,
}
```

- An example with keywords

  ```
  "Hello, how are you?".scan(/\w+/).any?{|k| keywords.key?(k)}    # => true
  ```
- An example without keywords

  ```
  "hello, who are you?".scan(/\w+/).any?{|k| keywords.key?(k)}    # => false
  ```

Answer (score -1):

To check if at least one keyword is in the string, do:

```
keywords = ["hello", "how"]
r = Regexp.new(keywords.join("|")) # case-sensitive
r.match("Hello, how are you?").nil? => false
r.match("no keywords exist").nil? => true
```

For faster regular expressions, use https://github.com/mudge/re2. It is a ruby wrapper for Googles re2 https://code.google.com/p/re2/

Comment: That is what the OP already has, and what the OP is trying not to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried similar method, but the performance didn't show obvious improvement. I will try re2, but now sure it could be used on AWS EMR or not.

Comment: EMR uses EC2 instances? If yes, compile re2 and install the gem afterwards. This should work.